# how to extract a 2D array encoded in a list of strings in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

I have messed up a dataframe.
I have a columns which contain strings which encode a list of numbers

e.g.

```
df=
                                    mycol
0   '[ 0.5497076,   0.59722222,  0.42361111]'  
1   '[ 0.8030303,   0.69090909,  0.52727273]'  
2   '[ 0.51461988,  0.38194444,  0.66666667]'
```

EDIT: actually, the commas are missing as well

```
df=
                                    mycol
0   '[ 0.5497076   0.59722222  0.42361111]'  
1   '[ 0.8030303   0.69090909  0.52727273]'  
2   '[ 0.51461988  0.38194444  0.66666667]'
```

Each of the strings encodes a list with a fixed number of elements.
I would like to convert this `mycol` into 3 (in general N, where `N=len(df[mycol][0])` `columns` each of them numeric, containing one element from the original list in mycol

I have tried the following, without success

```
df[mycol]=df[mycol].apply(lambda s: s.split())
df[mycol]=df[mycol].apply(lambda s: np.fromstring(s))

df[['mycol1','mycol2','mycol3']] = pd.DataFrame(df[mycol].values.tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"mycol": ['[ 0.5497076   0.59722222  0.42361111]', '[ 0.8030303   0.69090909  0.52727273]']})
df[['mycol1','mycol2','mycol3']]  = df["mycol"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split()).apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                   mycol     mycol1      mycol2      mycol3
0  [ 0.5497076   0.59722222  0.42361111]  0.5497076  0.59722222  0.42361111
1  [ 0.8030303   0.69090909  0.52727273]  0.8030303  0.69090909  0.52727273
```

Comment: you answer is great...However, my question was flawed since I do not have the commas in the string, so it does not work yet

Comment: This should help. `print(df["mycol"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split()))`

Comment: you comment combined with a df['mycol'].apply(pd.Series) worked. please edit the answer so I can accept it

Comment: Updated snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list as Dictionary and then directly convert it into a DataFrame -

```
import re
def stringtodict(x):
    d = {}
    x = x.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").strip()
    x = re.split("\\s{1,}", x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        d[str(i)] = float(x[i])
    return d

pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].apply(stringtodict).tolist())
```

I have edited the code for spaces as delimiter

Comment: I like your solution but @Rakesh arrived first with something very similar